# Gradine that doesn't take entire height of generated image

Tags: css, gradient

I need to achieve this effect: (fucsia is transparent)

[image]

I want to use this snipped I've prepared to achieve it:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/100);
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 2s ease;
}
div:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/ByZqvK

I need to generate a CSS gradient that looks like this picture: (fucsia is transparent)

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: Use a pseudo-element to create the bar instead of a background.

Comment: @danko this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEZVbo

Comment: I have to apply it to an input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a color stop as follows~:

```css
div {
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px ;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
  transparent, 
  transparent 90%, 
  blue 90%, 
  blue)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like this?

```css
.this {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.this div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.this:hover div {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="this">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to create this type of design using gradients, you could use [this generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) which would let you define "a transparent" part to your background